# Javascript Infinite Scroll inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, infinite-scroll

I am trying to create an infinite loading page with the use of javascript. I found this: [How to do infinite scrolling with javascript only without jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268079/how-to-do-infinite-scrolling-with-javascript-only-without-jquery/22268622#22268622?newreg=16070926cc03410781c4799241e3f670)

I have been playing with the last answer that links to this jsfiddle page: http://jsfiddle.net/8LpFR/

```
 document.addEventListener("scroll", function (event) {
      checkForNewDiv();
 });

 var checkForNewDiv = function () {
      var lastDiv = document.querySelector("#scroll-content > div:last-child");
      var lastDivOffset = lastDiv.offsetTop + lastDiv.clientHeight;
      var pageOffset = window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight;

      if (pageOffset > lastDivOffset - 10) {
          var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
          newDiv.innerHTML = "my awesome new div";
          document.getElementById("scroll-content").appendChild(newDiv);
          checkForNewDiv();
      }
 }; 
 checkForNewDiv();
```

How would I modify that in order to make the scrolling work inside a div rather than as the whole page? As in, what would lastDivOffset and pageoffset change to?

Comment: `lastInnerDiv.offsetTop + ...` and `outerDiv.offsetTop + ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution without creating any new wrapper division.

```
document.getElementById("scroll-content").addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.innerHTML = "my awesome new div";
  document.getElementById("scroll-content").appendChild(newDiv);
});

var checkForNewDiv = function() {
  var lastDiv = document.querySelector("#scroll-content > div:last-child");
  var maindiv = document.querySelector("#scroll-content");
  var lastDivOffset = lastDiv.offsetTop + lastDiv.clientHeight;
  var pageOffset = maindiv.offsetTop + maindiv.clientHeight;

  if (pageOffset > lastDivOffset - 10) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.innerHTML = "my awesome new div";
    document.getElementById("scroll-content").appendChild(newDiv);
    checkForNewDiv();
  }
};

checkForNewDiv();
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8LpFR/2/)

Comment: The OP specified the div wrapper: quote `.. in order to make the scrolling work inside a div ...`

Answer (score 5):

Simplest of them all.

```
var scrollY = container.scrollHeight - container.scrollTop;
var height = container.offsetHeight;
var offset = height - scrollY;

if (offset == 0 || offset == 1) {
    // load more content here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it within a div with `overflow:auto` and `position:relative`, so it will act as the body.
Also remember to specify a height.

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Then, you must change the JS references that pointed to body or window, to the new wrapper div:

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");

wrapper.addEventListener("scroll", function (event) {
    checkForNewDiv();
});

var checkForNewDiv = function () {
    var lastDiv = document.querySelector("#scroll-content > div:last-child");
    var lastDivOffset = lastDiv.offsetTop + lastDiv.clientHeight;
    var pageOffset = wrapper.scrollTop + wrapper.clientHeight;

    //NOTE THAT PROPERTIES NAME ALSO CHANGED A BIT, FOR EXAMPLE:
    // pageYOffset -> scrollTop   and    innerHeight -> clientHeight

    if (pageOffset > lastDivOffset - 10) {
        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.innerHTML = "my awesome new div";
        document.getElementById("scroll-content").appendChild(newDiv);
        checkForNewDiv();
    }
};

checkForNewDiv();
```

Here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8LpFR/1/

Answer (score 0):

For achieving that behaviour you don't really need to be using the `onScroll` event, it does have a very bad performance hit: you want to be using the `IntersectionObserver API` instead.

All you need to do is place element/s and listen for when they become available/unavailable in the screen. You only have to define a strategy on where and how you will display those items. You can customise the `root` element, define some `rootMarging` a `threeshold`... possibilites are endless :)

It's super easy to accomplish and with very few lines you can have a custom performant scrolling feature.

I recently put together an article about infinite scrolling and this specific behaviour [here](https://dioxmio.medium.com/infinite-scroll-done-the-right-way-33cb7be18407) if you are curious to know more with some examples

Answer (score 0):

Based on TheRealChx101's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29694188/11138585).
add a `.onscroll` listener to listen on this event.

```
container.onscroll = () => {
    const scrollY = container.scrollHeight - container.scrollTop;
    const height = container.offsetHeight;
    const offset = height - scrollY;

    if (offset == 0 || offset == 1) {
      // load more content here
    }
};
```