# How to slow down a div auto scroll

Tags: javascript, ajax

I Have found an example of infinite scrolling [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23962761/5326036) it works as expected in its original state that I got it from the link but when I modify it to suit my needs the sensitivity of the scroll changes and goes wild. So what I am aiming to do is to slow down the scroll and show loading. The ajax call return a `new JsonResult`. The only thing I changed was instead of hardcoding the `newDiv.innerHTML` I did an ajax call which returns a single object.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    document.getElementById("scroll-content").addEventListener("scroll", function (event) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/api/socialapi/5", // <-- Where should this point?
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (gData) {
                var res = $.parseJSON(gData);
                var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
                newDiv.innerHTML = res.Query;
                document.getElementById("scroll-content").appendChild(newDiv);
            },
            error: function (errormessage) {
                alert("Failed");
            }
        })

    });



    var checkForNewDiv = function () {
    var lastDiv = document.querySelector("#scroll-content > div:last-child");
    var maindiv = document.querySelector("#scroll-content");
    var lastDivOffset = lastDiv.offsetTop + lastDiv.clientHeight;
    var pageOffset = maindiv.offsetTop + maindiv.clientHeight;
    if (pageOffset > lastDivOffset - 10) {
        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.innerHTML = "my awesome new div2";
        document.getElementById("scroll-content").appendChild(newDiv);
        checkForNewDiv();
    }
    };

checkForNewDiv();
});
```

C# Method:

```
static int cc = 0;
// GET api/values/5
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult Get(int id)
{
    var jssp = new JSViewEditSocialQuery { presetid = "2", Query = "Test" + cc };        
    cc++;
    return new JsonResult(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jssp));
}
```

CSHTML:

```
<div class="Column">
    <div id="scroll-content">
        <div>test div</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: refer this link : it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950450/slow-scroll-speed-down

Comment: @megala Visually the speeds of the scrolling is fine, it's the items that are being added too fast for the scroll. Will slowing down the scroll trigger the event less?